# Extra blank page when I print (except in IE) - is it my print css?

Tags: css, printing, cross-browser

I am using print css to hide certain elements and also to stop page breaks when I don't want them. The user can choose to hide sections before they print.

My problem is that when I print-preview there is always an extra blank page (at the end in Chrome and Firefox, and at the beginning in Opera) and I cannot figure out why. IE does not have a problem, no extra pages (which is shocking...)

I would greatly appreciate some input. I have tried making the container div page-break-after: avoid; and page-break-after: auto; but neither worked. Also taking out the table.plain { page-break-inside:avoid; } did not make a difference.

The exclude class is added to a table when the user clicks the hide icon. This works and anything with the exclude class does not show in print. The final page the user wants to print may fit on one page or may not.

Here is my html:

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="side" class="exclude">
                ...logo, etc, shown at side on screen...
            </div>            
            <div id="data">
                <table class="printOnly plain printHeader">
                    ...logo, etc, to print at top...
                </table>                
                <div>
                    <table class="detail plain">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="rel">
                                    <div class="abs exclude visibility">
                                        <a href="#" class="show ico-show ico hid">Show</a>
                                        <a href="#" class="hide ico-hide ico">Hide</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <h3>Contact</h3>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            ...more tr with contact details...
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    ...more tables with other details...
                </div>
            </div> //data
        </div> //content
    </div> //main
</body>
```

Here is my print css:

```
@media print {
    .exclude {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .printOnly {
        display:block !important;
    }

    div#data,
    div#data div {
        width: 98% !important;
        border: none !important;
    }

    table.plain { page-break-inside:avoid; }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Not that it should matter, but have you tried setting a height of 0 to the excluded elements?

Comment: Please specify the IE version(s) that you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Nix - thank for the suggestion, but it made no difference.

Comment: @Spudley Problem isn't IE (presumably). It's everything else.

Comment: @tekiegirl Maybe you could debug it by loading the print stylesheet in the browser?

Comment: @Spudley Sorry to not be clearer - IE is the only browser that is working (not showing an extra blank page before or after what I want to print), the problem is that Chrome, Firefox and Opera do have the extra page. I am using IE 10, Firefox 21, and Opera 12.15.

Comment: Just tested in Safari 5.1.7 and there are no extra pages. IE and Safari: good, everything else: bad.

Comment: @tekiegirl - sorry for misreading  :-)

Comment: Chrome is 27.0.1453.110 m

Comment: @Nix Thanks for the suggestion but I am not sure what you mean. My print css is included in the stylesheet with most of my other css with a link in the head. I can view it in the Network tab in the debugger in Chrome, and it is loading fine. I think the print css is ok as it is at the beginning and usually if there is a problem it affects other styles declared later (ignoring everything after an error). There just seem to be rogue pagebreaks in some browsers, or maybe IE and Safari are ignoring an erroneous pagebreak.

Comment: @tekiegirl One thing you can do to debug it, is to open up the page in Chrome. In the dev tool, settings->overrides, there's an option to emulate CSS media. This makes it possible to see the page in the browser as if it was to be printed. You may then possibly see what's wrong. You could also simply change the media type of your print stylesheet to screen.

Comment: @Nix I changed it to screen and used the emulator and they both looked fine. I think it must be something to do with page breaks.

Comment: I seem to recall having a similar issue some years ago. The issue for me was that the blank page was being created not off the bottom of the content I wanted but off the side. In your print css try setting the width of the area you'd like to print to just a couple of hundred pixels to see if that helps.

Comment: @Doug You read my mind :) I just tried exactly that. Unfortunately with the same result. I cannot figure out where this extra page is coming from. In Chrome and Firefox it is at the end and in Opera it is at the beginning.

Comment: If you're not using a reset or normalize.css you might want to check margin and padding.

Answer (score 15):

Most of the times you’ll specify

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

The print driver in your browser doesn’t like this. So to fix that just add this to your print.css file

```
html, body { height: auto; }
```

No more blank page printing.

the solution is explained at this [page](http://notflip.be/?p=304)
hope helps everyone

Comment: Solved it for me. I implemented it using a media query in SCSS.

Comment: Just a broken link in there :(.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna suggest that you try using a CSS reset. Resets are supposed to help different browsers display the website in the same way. You could try the one at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ but I have never used it so I can't really say how it will work. You could also try googling for a CSS reset specifically for print styles.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox: If the blank page is visible at print preview, go to print--> page setup and reduce the scale until the blank disappears from print preview. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue using a media query instead of a separate print.css, try the following:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    @media print {
        /* This fixes an issue where when printing a selection,
         an extra blank page is printed in IE10 and IE11.
         Solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22320644/7752 */
        height: auto;
    }
}
```